# GraphQL Dataloader fails if backend returns null values

Tags: graphql, dataloader

I have a GraphQL object type Student. And each student may or may not have Phone data.
Phone is another GraphQL type object (A child object in Student).

I have GraphQL dataloader registered on Phone. Things work fine as long as each student record has a corresponding Phone record. But if there is any student record who does not have a corresponding phone record, Dataloader fails with error:

```
"message": "Exception while fetching data (/students[0]/phone) : The size of the promised values MUST be the same size as the key list",
```

I believe this is because, dataloader is trying to assert that size-of-keys-in-list should be same as size-of-values-resolved-in-list.

Is there anyway to accept null as values which is a valid case in my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Found that the backend server is not even sending 'null', it just ignores the missing record.

From official source:
https://github.com/graphql-java/java-dataloader/blob/7bf46ea182b1f8ab255c3107b1b61d4afd36ad88/src/main/java/org/dataloader/BatchLoader.java

Dataloader does support null values:

```
*
 * <pre>
 *  [
 *      { id: 2, name: 'San Francisco' },
 *      { id: 9, name: 'Chicago' },
 *      null,
 *      { id: 1, name: 'New York' }
 * ]
 * </pre>
```